# Prototype functions to classes and not ids elements

Tags: javascript, class, function, prototypejs

i'm new to prototype framework and i'm trying to apply some functions to **classes** elements and not ids elements.
This because I need to replicate every functions to various elements.
If I apply them to ids elements, only one of those get involved.

So, this is my script running with ids elements:

```
function removing (){
$('element').remove();
var data = $('element').innerHTML;
var wanted_count = 50;
var output = cutHtmlString(data, wanted_count);
$('element').replace(output);
}
```

the script remove and element of two and, and cuts the remaining one (an html string) and replace it.

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
function removing (){
$$('element').remove();
var data = $$('element').innerHTML;
var wanted_count = 50;
var output = cutHtmlString(data, wanted_count);
$$('element').replace(output);
}
```

thanks for helping

Comment: Could you post some markup to make your question a bit clearer please?

Comment: It's Magento blog section. I wanto to apply this script to every post in the list view. So I get: <php echo $post->getContent(); ?>. Previously I divided that post content in two ids elements, the firts time. I got wrong in my question script here, because the firts element must be "element1", the second/third is "element2". Sorry. At the end, I figured out I need to use classes elements instead of these ids ones.

Answer (score 0):

'$$' returns an array, even if there happens to be only one result.

So you cannot apply functions such as remove() to the result of $$.

You probably want

$$('element').invoke('remove');

However, there is another problem: $$ takes a CSS rule, so $$('element'), though syntactically valid, would match only things matched by the CSS rule 'element' - i.e. DOM elements with tag 'element', and there aren't any in HTML.

If what you mean is all elements with class 'element', then the code is

$$('.element').invoke('remove');

Comment: Yes I mean that,thanks, but..should I use the same method 'invoke' also for the other functions in my script. So: $$('.element').invoke('innerHTML'); and $$('.element').invoke('replace'); ??

Comment: Yes, you can, but you'll need to give them the required further arguments: $$('.element').invoke('innerHTML', html);